# Handle touch listeners in ViewPager with an inner fragment within a fragment

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using a `ViewPager` with an `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` in order to show a list of fragments `Group A`, thats allows me to swipe between fragments by touch. Each fragment from `Group A` holds an inner fragment `Group B`.

In one of the fragments from `Group B`, there is a `Chart` object which enables a horizontal scrolling which intercepts with the touch listeners.

I couldn't figure how to avoid the `Group A` scorlling (The `ViewPager` swipe) when the user tries to scroll the data in the `Chart` object.

[image]

As it shown in the picture:

- the `Chart` is painted in grey.
- `Group A` are the 2 fragments: white and green (picture taken in the swipe time)
- `Group B` the red inner fragment.

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable swipe ability of your view pager when user touches your charts and give it back when user stops touching your chart. First define a `Non-Swipable ViewPager` and make your view pager NonSwipable.

```
public class NonSwipableViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private boolean canScroll = true;
    public NonSwipableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public NonSwipableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public void setCanScroll(boolean canScroll) {
        this.canScroll = canScroll;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return canScroll && super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return canScroll && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public boolean isCanScroll() {
        return canScroll;
    }
}
```

Keep it in a public variable. (Keeping it with a public variable in activity may not be de best practice.)

Add a touch listener to your chart and disable swipe ability of your view pager like below:

```
            View yourChart = (YourChart) view.findViewById(R.id.your_chart);
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        if (activity.mainViewPager != null) {
                            activity.mainViewPager.setCanScroll(false);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (activity.mainViewPager != null) {
                            activity.mainViewPager.setCanScroll(true);
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, i will check it asap!, but i am afraid that i'd tryed something similiar before.

Comment: no problem. but this's a working code. i use it in a production app.

Comment: You're welcome. You accepted my answer but i could not get the bounty points (+50) can you help? thanks.

Comment: I had three hours countdown to reward, in ~30 min it will happen, thank you